# Trying to insert into new table but seeing "Could not find output table"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I have a SQL server backend, and an Access front end. The SQL table is updated daily, however once a week (or whenever I run this query) I need all the changes to be exported into a new table (upload), where the data doesn't match a static table I have. So basically I am trying to dedupe the live table (MSTR-SENT) off a static table (dedupe).

When I run this query (data-definition against a inked table in Access) I am getting the error "Could not find the output table 'upload'". Which is correct, as it doesn't exist, I just want to create a new table with the dedupe content (upload).

```
INSERT INTO [upload]
  (company, [new-ind], [address], [state], city, zip, stext)
SELECT de.company,
       de.[new-ind],
       de.[address],
       de.[state],
       de.[city],
       de.[zip],
       de.stext
  FROM [MSTR-SENT] de
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT website, company, zip
                    FROM dedupe d2
                   WHERE d2.website = de.website OR d2.company = de.company OR d2.zip = de.zip)
```

How would this work so it's inserting into a new table and doesn't throw this error?

Comment: You either need to create the table "upload" or use select into. But if you use select into it will only work once because then the table will exist.

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  The error message is pretty clear.  Have you checked whether you have table `upload` or not?

Comment: @Eric I am a sys admin, who also works with databases occasionally. I knew there was something simple I was missing, and this thread showed that! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INSERT INTO ...` statement must reference a table that **exists**. If you want to create the table, use an `INSERT...SELECT...INTO...` statement:

```
SELECT de.company,
       de.[new-ind],
       de.[address],
       de.[state],
       de.[city],
       de.[zip],
       de.stext
  INTO dbo.upload
  FROM [MSTR-SENT] de
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT website, company, zip
                    FROM dedupe d2
                   WHERE d2.website = de.website OR d2.company = de.company OR d2.zip = de.zip)
```

Of course, as you *should* expect, the above will fail if the table `upload` exists. But if that's the case, and the table is going to be effectively in "limbo" (sometimes there, sometimes not), then it seems you have a more fundamental design flaw, and you show stop dropping the table, and use the exist `INSERT INTO` you have.

If it's simple becase you want the table to be "empty" first, then `TRUNCATE` the table `upload` first.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple. Basically, the information that is posted into the table "upload" which is then.. uploaded into another platform, and the table is then deleted. The next time the query is ran, the table "dedupe" will have those results inserted into it so the next "upload" is still only new results. However, I can also just truncate like you said too, Thank you!